# TimescaleDB how to alter the retention policy's time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, postgresql-9.1, timescaledb

In timescale DB, it is not allowed to alter the retention time interval of a hyper table. Is there any work around or other ways to alter the time interval after a retention policy is set for a hypertable?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the retention policy using [remove_retention_policy](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/data-retention/create-a-retention-policy/#creating-automatic-data-retention-policies) and then add it back with the desired interval

Comment: Remove/Add is the easiest way since there can only be one retention policy per hypertable.

That said, you can always look at any currently running job through the informational views and update the configuration as needed.

See your jobs and look at the `config` column: https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/informational-views/jobs/

Alter the config of a specific job (or temporarily disable it, change schedule interval, etc.): https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/actions/alter_job/

Answer (score 0):

1. Update retention policy

```sql
SELECT add_retention_policy('<table_name>', INTERVAL '1 hour');
```

2. Use this query to see scheduled data retention jobs

```sql
SELECT j.hypertable_name,
       j.job_id,
       config,
       schedule_interval,
       job_status,
       last_run_status,
       last_run_started_at,
       js.next_start,
       total_runs,
       total_successes,
       total_failures
  FROM timescaledb_information.jobs j
  JOIN timescaledb_information.job_stats js
    ON j.job_id = js.job_id
  WHERE j.proc_name = 'policy_retention';
```

3. Get the job_id from the above table
4. Run this query to alter the job's schedule_interval

```sql
SELECT alter_job(1000, schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hour');
```